# How to download/map date from Firestore into a Swift Collection View

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mapping, collectionview

I am able to download the data & see it in the Xcode debug console when I print ("(products)" after completion(true) but when I try to use the products variable in the View Controller & print it's contents there I get an empty array []. How do I use the data after in a collection view after it is downloaded?

1. Model

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

public struct StoreProducts: Codable {

    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var orderNumber: Int?
    var country: String?
    var description: String?
    var price: Int?
    var duration: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case orderNumber
        case country
        case description
        case price
        case duration
    }
}
```

2. Model Class

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class StoreViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    public static let shared = StoreViewModel()
    
    private let productsCollection: String = "products/country/subscription"
    
    @Published var products : [StoreProducts]?
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  
    public func fetchProductData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        db.collection(canadianProductsCollection).getDocuments() { [self] (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            //Handle Error:
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                completion(false)
            } else {
                
                //No Documents Found:
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("no documents")
                    completion(false)
                    return
                }
                
                //Documents Found:
                let products = documents.compactMap { document -> StoreProducts? in
 
                    return try! document.data(as: StoreProducts.self)
                }
                
                completion(true)

                print ("\(products)")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. View Controller

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

@ObservedObject private var storeViewModel = StoreViewModel()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        StoreViewModel.shared.fetchProductData(completion: { success in
            if success {

              print("Data loaded successfully")
              print (storeViewModel.products)

            } else {

              //some break routine

            }
        })
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using a local variable `let products = ...`, you probably want to store the result into your `@Published var products : [StoreProducts]?`.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the results from the database to a local variable and it is not passed on to your storeViewModel.

```
    products = documents.compactMap { document -> StoreProducts? in
 
        return try! document.data(as: StoreProducts.self)
   }
```

I think removing the "let" might solve the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help, products now stores the data from firebase when I print it inside the StoreViewModel, however when I use it in the HomeViewController storeViewModel.products comes up as nil

Comment: That is probably because when you declare storeViewModel in your HomeViewController, you declare a new instance of the viewModel, which has no data and not the singleton viewModel that you've already created). What you want to do is return the shared instance of the viewModel

Comment: How would the code look like for that?

Comment: @ObservedObject private var storeViewModel = StoreViewModel.shared